# Spring 4, JUnit 4 without spring boot NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type

Tags: java, spring, junit4, springjunit4classrunner

I have a Spring 4.3 application which works fine.
I'm trying to use JUnit 4.11 but the context doesn't load.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'caesb.websupport.service.BatchSolicitacaoService' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}

**base-spring-application.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>  
  ....
    <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="caesb">
    </context:component-scan>
</beans>
```

**test-spring-application.xml**

It has only datasource configuration.

**BatchSolicitacaoService.java**

```
@Service
public class BatchSolicitacaoService extends BaseEntityService<BatchSolicitacao>
{
...
}
```

**PriorizacaoHidrometroDWService.java**

```
@Service
public class PriorizacaoHidrometroDWService extends BaseEntityService<PriorizacaoHidrometroDW>
{
...
   @Inject 
   private BatchSolicitacaoService batchSolicitacaoService;

}
```

**BasicTest.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestExecutionListeners( { DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath*:/base-spring-application.xml","classpath*:/test-spring-application.xml"})
@Transactional
public class BasicTest
{
    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("teste teste");
    }
}
```

I have added @TestExecutionListeners, but without success. 
I removed @Transaction, but also without success.

Comment: I believe your Spring context is not constructed as expected. Can you try using @ContextConfiguration(classes = YourMainClass.class) just to test?

Comment: what is the classpath* for ? put directly the name of your config file (if it is in your resources folder of course) : @ContextConfiguration({"classpath:base-spring-application.xml","classpath:test-spring-application.xml"})

Comment: I do not know if I made it clear, but the application run normally with these settings.
This problem only happens in unit tests.